# function defined as integral of borel function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, markov-process

I know that $f \in B_b(E)$, where $B_b(E)$ is the set of Borel bounded function on an euclidean space E. I have to show that:
\begin{equation}
x \to \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-at} P_tf(x) dt
\end{equation}
is a Borel and bounded function, where $a \in (0, +\infty)$, $P_tf \colon B_b(E) \to B_b(E)$ is an operator.
How can I argue?

Comment: What do you know about the family $\{P_t\}$? Just assuming that $P_t$ maps bounded Borel functions to bounded Borel functions for each $t$ doesn't seem sufficient.

Comment: It is a semigroup. $P_tf(x)=\int_{E}f(y)p(t,x,dy)$ where $p(t,x,dy)$ is a transition probability function

Comment: Look at (the proof of) Fubini's theorem. Measurability of the integral w.r.t. one of the variables is part of the statement.

Comment: @Jochen I don't understand in which way Fubini's theorem can help me..

Comment: In Fubini's formula for $\int_A\int_B f(x,y) d\nu(y) d\mu(x)$ one needs and proves the measurability of $x\mapsto \int_B f(x,y)d\nu(y)$. This is very similar to your measurability question, isn't it?.